How to implement ordering for VAR impulse response functions in statsmodels (python)
I'm trying to implement an impulse response function for a VAR system. However, I'm not sure how to implement the variable ordering. Does this correspond to the order of the columns in the data frame? I've changed this around but without any changes to the impulse response functions. PLease help.

Are they so-called "orthogonalized"/"structural" impulse responses? If they're not, then the ordering of the variables is immaterial.

thank you I see that the order does in fact matter when i set orth = True.
